# Laravel nested eloquent relationships using model

Tags: laravel

I am trying to getting the more sorted object as output using laravel eloquent relationships

```
Section::with(['fieldTypes','fields'=>
        function ($query) use ($id) {
            $query->where('user_id', '=', $id);
        },
        'fields.fieldType'=> function ($query)  {
            $query->select('id','type','url','icon');
        }])->get();
```

**Output**

```
"fields": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "user_id": 1,
                        "field_type_id": 1,
                        "section_id": 3,
                        "title": "Facebook",
                        "value": "inderjit",
                        "order": 1,
                        "field_type": {
                            "id": 1,
                            "type": "facebook",
                            "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
                        }
                    }
                ]
```

I want output like this . I want to merge 2 objects as one

```
"fields": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "field_type_id": 1,
        "section_id": 3,
        "title": "Facebook",
        "value": "inderjit",
        "order": 1,
        "type": "facebook",
        "url": "https://www.facebook.com/"
    }
]
```

Comment: But you have an id field in the outer object as well as the inner object. But anyway you can use the map method of the collection to achieve this. Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-map

Answer (score 0):

Something like this. You can add a method in your model where you trigger a leftJoin. Then you have the fields of the relation in the model.

```php
public function scopeJoinWithFieldTypes($query)
{
    return $query->leftJoin("field_types", "field_type.id", "=", "fields.id");
}
```